# What URL will Googlebot crawl when you use the meta fragment tag with a regular hash URL?

Tags: ajax, crawlable-ajax

my client wants to use [AJAX crawling](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification) (I know that it is deprecated
But he wants it to use because of another search engine that still support it such as yandex.ru)

So I have URL like this:

```
http://example.com/#/card/card_slug?category=car
```

I feel it pretty ugly to transform it to this:

```
http://example.com/#!/card/card_slug?category=car
```

So I decided to use  `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`

What page will Googlebot look for when he goes to this page:

```
http://example.com/#/card/card_slug?category=car
```

(like `example.com?category=car&_escaped_fragment_=#/card/card_slug`)

Comment: Have you tried [fetch and render tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch) in search console to know how Google view your site? I can't say how Googlebot view your page after [Ajax deprecated](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
http://example.com/#!/card/card_slug?category=car
```

fetched as following and indexed.

```
http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/card/card_slug%3Fcategory%3Dcar
```

single # url's are not crawled /i'm not sure/ and 
definitely not indexed

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch?hl=en&siteUrl=

Use the above link to fetch your URL in search console and Google will likely tell you what page it fetched with your # parameter in the URL.

I think the most likely result is that it will ignore everything after the # and only fetch example.com, but I am not sure.